# What is the type should the create method of the repository return?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, cqrs

I am trying to implement the CQRS pattern.

Following the CQRS pattern, the `Command` should return nothing, as the `void` type in Java.

The `create()` method in the repository is the command in my opinion and it should return nothing following the pattern.

But I am struggling to build the function which needs to create and use the new entity.

For example, I have to build a function `assign new child category`. In this feature, the client can either send the `parent category id` or `new child details` to the server.

The `parent category id` is an easy case, but the problem is in the `new child details` case.

I have to create a new category base on the details first, then use that entity to assign the parent id to it, and finally save it. Currently, I am not able to get the newly created entity, because the `create()` method returns nothing.

And I can't create a new entity, assign the parent id and save it, because the entity can't be created without an id and the id is only assigned by the ORM I am using.

---

What should I do to solve this problem? Does the method `create()` of the repository return an entity other than `void` violate the CQRS pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on scenario & business needs. All the design patterns, approaches, etc. just give you an idea of possible solutions to common problems. There is no single good principle to follow that works for all the scenarios across different business problems. If after executing the command, each time you need to execute some logic based on the result - then return that result to avoid unnecessary calls. It all depends on the problem you try to solve & trade-offs you are ready to make.

For more info you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433318/cqrs-command-return-values).

Comment: So I could return the newly created entity to the client without making another call and still following the CQRS pattern?

Comment: I quote a sentence from the link I shared above:
*"if a CQRS command is capable of returning a success/failure indicating completion status, then a return value makes sense. This includes returning a new DB row identity, or any result that does not read or return domain model (business) content."*

Comment: In fact, you can use both. You can have two interfaces: a regular one and a generic one. Use the regular one for standart purposes & use the generic one when you need a result. Since I don't know your architecture, business, etc. I can't say which one will work best for you. But I hope you got the idea, that it pretty much depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

> Following the CQRS pattern, the Command should return nothing, as the void type in Java.

I don't know where this is coming from, it's been years that people believe this, but it is not true.

For entities creation, or you tell the storage the id for the new thing to store, or it creates it for you and you can get it (or the entire entity) as a return, it doesn't violate anything.

Comment: I'm using .NET stack and Microsoft has a [misleading article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs) on the topic. I honestly haven't seen a really good, *"proper"* description of the topic. If you know any good resource, please share.

Comment: This is something https://youtu.be/JHGkaShoyNs (from minute 44 on), CQRS is about models more than messages and rules

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This guy's stile reminds me of Uncle Bob. He's definately inspired by him lol. But his main focus was on queries and he also mentioned that Commands return void

Comment: Commands as per CQS definition, in fact he also challenge that saying, how do you implement stack.pop() in that way?

Comment: Ah, okay, true 

Answer (score 0):

Returning an entity doesn't violate CQRS Pattern.

In your Command Model add this:

```
public record CreateCommand : IRequest<ModelVm>
```

Which `ModelVm` is the model you want to return.

And in your `CommandHandler` class add this code :

```
public class CreateCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateCommand, ModelVm>
```

And instead of returning `Unit.Value` You should return `ModelVm` in `CreateCommandHandler`.